# How to use wordpress shortcodes in custom php file folder?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I want to display wp formcraft (plugin) in my custom PHP file so I wanted to use "do_shortcode()" function but nothing works it just shows white screen.

my php file code:

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include_once $path . '/wp-config.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php';
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
echo apply_filters( "the_content","[fc id='1'][/fc]");
```

?>

Comment: This is how you use the shortcode `echo do_shortcode( '[fc id='1'][/fc]' );`. Try. What file are yo u adding thi sin ?

Comment: @Bhanu i got a blank white page after using your method

Comment: Where do you want to display the output of shortocde ?

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned all the way up, both in PHP and WordPress?

Comment: @Bhanu i created a folder outside php...

Comment: @Chris Haas, no error but just a blank white page

Comment: @Bhanu i mean outside wordpress folder

Comment: Loading just `wp-load.php` should be enough, so no need to manually load the other core files. And what's the code for the shortcode (`fc`) handler function? Does `[fc id='1'][/fc]` actually display the expected value when used on standard WordPress posts and pages?

Comment: @SallyCJ yes it display on stanndard wordpress post and pages

Comment: Try adding `var_dump( shortcode_exists( 'fc' ) );` before the `echo` and see if the dump says `true`..

Comment: @SallyCj It works but got this issue `bool(true)
[[[["field6","contains","Other"]],[["show_fields","field8"]],"and"]]
1 Step 1` and i think the css is not found.

Comment: Sorry for not answering that (yet), but actually, what does your PHP file do? Why does it need to be in a custom folder? Can't you just use the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) to deliver the form? That way, you won't need to manually load `wp-load.php` etc. because WordPress will already or automatically be initialized just as on standard WordPress posts and pages. You could even just create a Page (post type `page`) and use a custom template with your form or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what your doing, but i guess you want to do something like this:

```php
function xyz() {
  do_shortcode("[fc id='1'][/fc]");
}
echo apply_filters("the_content", "xyz");
```